# Can't move file php with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

executing the following code, I get this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/chroot/home/xxxx/public_html/Project/img/uploads/ee9b37faf0390088b3bd4b1eb0d3b862.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /chroot/home/xxxx/public_html/Project/php/class/edit_profile_form.php on line 101

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpBXXoJs' to '/chroot/home/xxxx/public_html/Project/img/uploads/ee9b37faf0390088b3bd4b1eb0d3b862.jpg' in /chroot/home/xxxx/public_html/Project/php/class/edit_profile_form.php on line 101
```

Code:

```
$target_dir = "/chroot/home/xxxx/public_html/Project/img/uploads/";
$db_target_dir = "/~xxxx/Project/img/uploads/";
$this->target_file = $target_dir . md5($this->username);
$db_target_dir=$db_target_dir.md5($this->username);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["photo"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $imageFileType;

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ){
        $this->message="Errore: formato not supported";
        return false;
}

$this->target_file=$this->target_file.".".$imageFileType;
$db_target_dir=$db_target_dir.".".$imageFileType;
if ((!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $this->target_file)) || ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 150000)){
        $this->message="Error2";
        return false;
}
$this->target_file=$db_target_dir;

                }
```

I have the permission to write on the folder, but I can't figure out why I have this problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to be sure, try connecting as the user running Apache and create the file using `touch /chroot/home/xxxx/public_html/Project/img/uploads/ee9b37faf0390088b3bd4b1eb0d3b862.jpg `. That will prove that Apache user has no permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clearly the permissions.  You said that *you* have permission to write to the folder, but what about the user, under which the web server runs?

Have a look at the owner of the temp file that's being created - it will be something like `www-data` or such like.  Then ensure that this user has write permissions to the destination folder.

Comment: It could be a permission problem on the source file, too (this is a move, after all)

Comment: @whites11 No, it couldn't.  The error message states `failed to open stream: Permission denied in [target directory]`.